# echo email address over to next page on click and send email to that email using $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, email

i am trying to echo an email address onto the next page 'send_email.php' through a link using the url.

The idea is that send_email.php sends out an email to the specific email address for which that link belongs.

i am currently getting undefined index 'contact_email' errors and i am not sure what i am doing wrong, i am trying to use $_GET as a means to retrieve the email address from the url and add this to the email to/recipient line in send_email.php

our link is on 'page1' where we use a mysql query to pull details from the database like so:

```
$myId2 = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $query2 = mysql_query(" SELECT supplier_registration.contact_name, 
                               supplier_registration.contact_email, supplier_registration.contact_number, supplier_registration.company_address, supplier_registration.company_postcode
                        FROM supplier_registration 
                        INNER JOIN supplier_stats
                        ON supplier_registration.company_reg_number = supplier_stats.company_reg_number
                        WHERE supplier_stats.id = $myId2 AND supplier_stats.insurance_date = DATE(NOW())");
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $query2 )) {
        echo "<div class=\"contact_details\">Contact Details:<br/>";    
        echo "<p><font color=\"#999\">Contact Name:</font> ".$row2['contact_name']."<br/>";
        echo "<font color=\"#999\">Contact Number:</font> ".$row2['contact_number']."<br/>";
        echo "<p><font color=\"#999\">Contact Email:</font> ".$row2['contact_email']."<br/></p>";

        echo "<p><font color=\"#999\">Postal Address:</font> ".$row2['company_address']."</br>";
        echo "<font color=\"#999\">Contact Name:</font> ".$row2['company_postcode']."</p>";
        echo "</div>";

        echo "<a href=\"send_email.php?email=".$row2['contact_email']."\"\"><div class=\"buttons\">Send Reminder Email</div> </a>";
```

then when we click the link we go to send_email.php which looks like this:

```
<?php
$_GET['contact_email'];
$myEmail = $_GET['contact_email'];

 $to = $myEmail;
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Email successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Email delivery failed…</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

but i am getting these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: contact_email in C:\xampp\htdocs\hewden_spms\send_email.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: contact_email in C:\xampp\htdocs\hewden_spms\send_email.php on line 3
Email successfully sent!
```

can someone please show me where the problem is and how i can get this to work thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are passing parameter through anchor tag with parameter as `email` in

```
 echo "<a href=\"send_email.php?email=".$row2['contact_email']."\"\"><div class=\"buttons\">Send Reminder Email</div> </a>";
                                ^
```

and is trying to access like `$_GET['contact_email'];` in *send_email.php*.

You have to use the parameter name you have used while passing, in the `GET`. So change to `$_GET['email'];`

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="send_email.php?email="` your query string paramter name is `email` not `contact_email`

It should be,

```
$_GET['email'];
$myEmail = $_GET['email'];
```

instead of

```
$_GET['contact_email'];
$myEmail = $_GET['contact_email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the $_GET parameter to be called 'email' in this line: `<a href=\"send_email.php?email=".$row2['contact_email'].`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
echo "<a href=\"send_email.php?contact_email=".$row2['contact_email']."\"\"><div class=\"buttons\">Send Reminder Email</div> </a>";
```

instead of

```
echo "<a href=\"send_email.php?email=".$row2['contact_email']."\"\"><div class=\"buttons\">Send Reminder Email</div> </a>";
```

you are passing email=$row2['contact_email'] it means that your key is email and value is what comes in $row2['contact_email'], value could be anything but you can get value by key which is email.